# C library message queue didn't read all messages

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I'm running this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

// Define a structure for our messages
struct message {
  long msg_type;
  char msg_text[100];
};

int main() {
  key_t key;
  int msg_id;
  struct message msg;

  // Generate a key for the message queue
  key = ftok("progfile", 'A');

  // Create the message queue
  msg_id = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

  // Prepare messages to send
  struct message messages[3] = {{1, "This is message with priority 1"},
                                {2, "This is message with priority 2"},
                                {3, "This is message with priority 3"}};

  // Send the messages
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    msgsnd(msg_id, &messages[i], sizeof(messages[i]), 0);
  }

  // Receive the messages
  for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    if (msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, IPC_NOWAIT) != -1) {
      printf("Received message: %s\n", msg.msg_text);
    } else {
      printf("No message in the queue\n");
    }
  }

  // Destroy the message queue
  msgctl(msg_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

What I expect is it prints out all three messages, but actually it only prints:

```
Received message: This is a message with priority 1
No message in the queue
No message in the queue
```

And `msgctl` did not run because when I `ipcs`, I can still see the message queue alive even after this code finished.

From what I read, `msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, IPC_NOWAIT)` will read and remove the 1st message available, with the type arg set to `0`. But actually, it reads only 1 message and then it cannot read any message, which confused me. I debugged using gdb, and found that even when the message queue still has messages, `msgrcv` won't retrieve the message. The other strange thing is, if I split this code into two files and run the send and read logic in two processes, the read process can read all 3 messages. I don't know what is the difference here. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You barely have any kind of error checking. Have you removed it in your example shown here, or is the code you show the actual code you build and run? And for the only place you have error checking, you don't check what the actual error might be.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in `msgsnd` and `msgrcv`, they should be

```c
msgsnd(msg_id, &messages[i], sizeof(messages[i].msg_text), 0);
```

and

```c
if (msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg.msg_text), 0, IPC_NOWAIT) != -1)
```

The 3rd arg `msgsz` should only contain the size of the `msg_text` of the message.